# avplayer is not working in ios 4.3

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I have abillity to listen to mp3 song in my app. I am using AVPLAYER
Here is some code

```
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playingItemDidEnd) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:player]; 
    [player play];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(checkTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

So when i'm using ios 5.0 I have this in debug
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-02-27 15:21:27.717 LifesMusic[4161:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

But it still working. But in IOS 4.3 it is not working at all. Can somebody help me to fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: you should read Apples document [Multimedia Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6) and understand what you're doing …

Also make sure you linked the `AV Foundation` framework to your project, imported it properly and your controller "listens" to the AVAudioPlayerDelegate.

**In your controllers .h-file:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

**In your controllers .m-file:**

```
@synthesize player;
```

**In your method which 'plays' the song:**

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"song" ofType: @"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];
[fileURL release];
self.player = newPlayer;
[newPlayer release];

[player setDelegate: self];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

**Delegate method to repeat song:**

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer*)player successfully:(BOOL)completed {
    if (completed == YES) {
        [player play];
    }
}
```

Comment: i have avplayer not avaudioplayer

Comment: BUT AVAudioPlayer is recommended for audio … So you should follow Apples recommendations

Comment: OK. Thank you! I will make avaudioplayer

Answer (score 0):

I also received same error (OSStatus error 1685348671) when I tried to play mp3 files on iOS 4.3.

Later on I found that it was the mp3 sound problem which made it incompatible to be played in iOS 4.3. So, I used iTunes Player to convert new version of mp3 sound with existing one. Now it works fine and better.

Steps:

Open your current mp3 sound in iTunes
Select it and Click on "Advanced" Menu >> "Create MP3 Version"
It wil create copy of current audio. Use newly created mp3 file for your app.

It helped me. I hope it might help others as well. All the best!